# slideToggle effect JQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I try to use in Jquery with the slideToggle effect to show and hide 2 div's content while click on buttons...but it isn't working as i excepted. here the explanation:

THE PROBLEM

- you click on "button 1" the hidden div show up and bottom menu goes down and the green text display
- you click on "button 2" the other div with the blue text goes up and dispaly
- you clicked on "button 1" the div are display goes down and you see the text of "button 1"

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE

- you click on "button 1" the hidden div show up (green text) and bottom menu goes down.
- you click ONCE on "button 2" the current div disappear (visualy he slideUp) and the bottom menu
  goes up and immediately goes down and dispaly the text of "button 2" (blue text)
- when you click on "button 1" ONCE (the same action occur) the current div (with the blue text of
  button 2) disappear and the bottom menu goes up and down immediately and display the hidden div
  of button 1 (green text)
- if click on "button 1" or "button 2" (in the first time-as starting point) 
  the relevant div of the buttons will display (as step 1)
- and to close at all the "hidden" div - will be in the second click on the same button.

this is the link to preview in JSfiddle

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/GDdesign/P3Fuk/>
```

I hope that i was clear of my explaintation. :-)

For yours answers i will very appreciat,

GDdesign

Comment: Please include your relevant code! Don't trick the system by adding the jsFiddle link as code. That is just rude.

Comment: i dont know how to add a link to jsfiddle ..i try several times...i dont want to trick the system..this is my first time

Comment: you can see a globe icon on the top of the editor! use that to add links!

Comment: @user3792989 The way you did it before was just fine. *[ link-title  ] ( link-url )* without spaces of course. The problem is you must include the relevant part of your code *in* the post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery callback functions, change your js to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $('ul.btns').on('click', 'a', function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();  
        if ( $(this).hasClass('greenBtn') ) { 
            if ( $('#hide2').css('display') != 'none' ) { 
                $('#hide2').slideUp('2000', 'swing',function(){
                    $('#hide1').slideToggle('2000', 'swing'); 
                }); 
            }
            else
            {
                $('#hide1').slideToggle('2000', 'swing'); 
            }
        } else { 
            if ( $('#hide1').css('display') != 'none' ) { 
                $('#hide1').slideUp('2000', 'swing',function(){
                    $('#hide2').slideToggle('2000', 'swing'); 
                }); 
            }
            else
            {
                $('#hide2').slideToggle('2000', 'swing'); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle Link : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P3Fuk/3/)

Comment: rohanAM - yes i accept... please tell me where to click to do so? (i am new... )

Comment: 'Upword Arrow' on left side is for UPVOTE & 'Hollow Checkmark' is to ACCEPT answer, which will become green after you click on it!